# Convert hours to time in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, hour

How do I convert a vector of hours, such as 22.93, into the time of day?

So 22.93 should be converted to 22:55:48 pm? Thanks!

Comment: When the time is in a 24-hour format, AM / PM is usually not specified.. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: Maybe that is how the data was presented to me in a software. Maybe you are not smart enough to make other assumptions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83440-how-to-convert-from-decimal-time-to-hh-mm-ss), this can be done using [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html):

```
>> datestr(22.93/24,'HH:MM:SS')

ans =

22:55:48
```

Note that I am dividing by 24 because `datestr` expects the decimal part to represent a "percentage of a day" (which has 24 hours).

An example for a vector, also including the AM/PM suffix:

```
v = [22.93 13.6167 16.3334];
strcat(datestr(v(:)/24,'HH:MM:SS'),{' '},datestr(v(:)/24,'AM'))

ans = 

    '22:55:48 PM'
    '13:37:00 PM'
    '16:20:00 PM'
```

Note that here the result is a `cell` array of `char` row vectors, where in the first case it was `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are doing allows you to generate the time values I would recommend using the format below because all the functions are built in.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Otherwise if you have no control over how the data is presented to you, you might want to convert the vector into a cell array so you can use cellfun(functionName,matrix) on the cell array to apply the function "functionName" to each cell. Then all you have to do is write a function to convert the hour as a double into standard time format and replace functionName with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
% hours h minutes m seconds s
h0=22.93;

h=floor(h0)
m=floor( (h0-floor(h0))*60 ) 
s=60*( (h0-floor(h0))*60  -floor( (h0-floor(h0))*60 ) )
```